# User input: selecting pixel (point) in a video

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, matlab-figure

I want to write code that will open up a video player that the user can view frame-by-frame. Furthermore, I need the user to be able to click on a pixel on any of the frames such that the pixel's position is recorded. I've tried using implay and getpts, but these don't seem to work for what I'm doing, or maybe I'm not implementing them correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can record the pixel position as much as your mouse pointer position. That I know it can be obtained and probably store in a variable for later use.About the frame by frame animation, I assume it may depend of the video player capabilities of each user, and not sure you can guarantee the same experience on every single browser. sorry